# PyBrain - how to do Deep belief network training?

Tags: python, pybrain, deep-learning, dbn

I have some difficulty training a DBN using Pybrain. 
First I tried to do it the simple way:

```
net = buildNetwork(*layerDims)
```

I faced this problem: [How to do supervised deepbelief training in PyBrain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161295/how-to-do-supervised-deepbelief-training-in-pybrain) , and the suggested solution just led to another error:

```
File "/home/WORK/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-    py2.7.egg/pybrain/unsupervised/trainers/deepbelief.py", line 62, in <genexpr>
layercons = (self.net.connections[i][0] for i in layers)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So I tried to define a network from scratch!

```
inp = LinearLayer(3 , 'visible')
hidden0 = SigmoidLayer(2 , 'hidden0')
hidden1= SigmoidLayer(2 , 'hidden1')
output = LinearLayer(2 , 'output')
bias = BiasUnit('bias')
net = Network()
net.addInputModule(inp)
net.addModule(hidden0)
net.addModule(hidden1)
net.addModule(output)
net.addModule(bias)
net.addConnection(FullConnection(inp, hidden0))
net.addConnection(FullConnection(hidden0, hidden1))
net.addConnection(FullConnection(hidden1, output))
net.addConnection(FullConnection(bias, hidden0))
net.addConnection(FullConnection(bias, hidden1))
net.addConnection(FullConnection(bias, output))
net.sortModules()
```

still when I run:

```
trainer = deepbelief.DeepBeliefTrainer(net1, dataset=ds)
trainer.trainEpochs(epochs)
```

I see this error:

```
File "/home/WORK/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/structure/connections/connection.py", line 37, in __init__
self.outSliceTo = outmod.indim
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'indim'
```

which has something to do with the hidden layer in the related RBM.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You need to make an output module. So addModule(output) should be addOutputModule(output).

Comment: Pybrain is extremely slow library. I moved to other libraries such as caffe or c libraries, which are 25X faster or more.

Comment: Instead of this old library, I suggest looking at a [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/)-based library such as [Blocks](https://github.com/mila-udem/blocks).

Answer (score 1):

You initialize a network under the name `net`:

```
net = Network()
net.addInputModule(inp)
net.addModule(hidden0)
net.addModule(hidden1)
net.addModule(output)
net.addModule(bias)
net.addConnection(FullConnection(inp, hidden0))
net.addConnection(FullConnection(hidden0, hidden1))
net.addConnection(FullConnection(hidden1, output))
net.addConnection(FullConnection(bias, hidden0))
net.addConnection(FullConnection(bias, hidden1))
net.addConnection(FullConnection(bias, output))
net.sortModules()
```

But you pass as argument `net1`:

```
trainer = deepbelief.DeepBeliefTrainer(net1, dataset=ds)
trainer.trainEpochs(epochs)
```

This causes an error for sure.

So

```
trainer = deepbelief.DeepBeliefTrainer(net, dataset=ds)
```

should solve your problem.